# Speeding up script loading appointments from a Google calendar in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google-script in a spreadsheet that loads appointments from a calendar. It calculates the time spend on appointments. But to update the calendar items takes a very long time, I get often a timeout error. Fetching the appointments from the calendar is not the problem. Are the  queries in every 10 tabs of the spreadsheet, mentioned under the script, slowing things down?

```
function updateUren()
{

  var cal = CalendarApp.openByName("Uren");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Uren");

  //set first row
  var details=[["title", "date", "start", "end", "duration"]]; // events[i].getDescription(),
  var range=sheet.getRange(2,1,1,5);
  range.setValues(details);

  //gets the year from Boekjaar
  var year = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Boekjaar").getRange(2,1,1,1).getValue();

  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("January 1, "+year), new Date("December 31, "+year));
  if(events.length == 0)
  {
    Browser.msgBox('No events found for year: "' + year + '"');
  }
  for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
    //http://www.google.com/google-d-s/scripts/class_calendarevent.html
    var startTime = events[i].getStartTime();
    var endTime = events[i].getEndTime();
    var durationHours = (endTime - startTime) / (1000*60*60);
    var details=[[events[i].getTitle(), startTime, startTime, endTime, durationHours]]; // events[i].getDescription(),
    var row=i+3;
    range=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,5);
    range.setValues(details);
  }
  var foo = "foo";
}
```

I have 10 tabs that are running the query I show here. They filter the appointments duration for a specific period

```
=QUERY (Uren!A:E, "SELECT B, SUM(E) WHERE A CONTAINS 'SomeKeyWord' AND B>=DATETIME '2012-6-18 00:00:00'
AND B<DATETIME '2012-7-16 00:00:00' GROUP BY B PIVOT A'")
```

Are they expensive and slowing things down during a call to the updateUren() function?

Anyone knows the answer?

Comment: Your code looks incomplete. How did you deduce that the openByName() call is the cause of the delay. Can you please paste the complete code here

Comment: your code is incomplete... could you check it please ? thanks

Comment: Sorry forgot to encode lessthen char.

Comment: How do I know it's openByName(). By running the debugger with breakpoints. But I start to wonder if it's not what happens after the function what's slowing it down, because putting a breakpoint on var foo="foo"; and running after this stop seems to take the longest for now. I have 10 tabs that are running the query I added under the function. The filter the appointments duration for a specific period

Comment: maybe you could [try this app](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dE1rMnFLUUE0cmtGSmx2UVZ4djgzS2c#gid=0) to see if it is suffering from the same problem (run from the script editor once for authorization) if it doesn' then the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: It was not to slow at all. Only 5 seconds or so. Good enough for 169 appointments. The problem is probably the query. The script has to run it 10 times for 10 separate tabs. Group By Pivot might be the time consuming factor here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether the QUERY functions accessing the data has anything to do with it (it might), but my understanding is that it is best practice to not do gets/sets inside loops as this can slow things down considerably.  Instead, build your array first and then set it with one setValues() call.

```
function updateUren()
{

  var cal = CalendarApp.openByName("Uren");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Uren");

  //create first row of 2D array
  var details=[["title", "date", "start", "end", "duration"]]; // events[i].getDescription(),

  //gets the year from Boekjaar
  var year = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Boekjaar").getRange(2,1,1,1).getValue();

  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("January 1, "+year), new Date("December 31, "+year));
  if(events.length == 0)
  {
    Browser.msgBox('No events found for year: "' + year + '"');
  }

  for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
    //http://www.google.com/google-d-s/scripts/class_calendarevent.html
    var startTime = events[i].getStartTime();
    var endTime = events[i].getEndTime();
    var durationHours = (endTime - startTime) / (1000*60*60);
    details.push([events[i].getTitle(), startTime, startTime, endTime, durationHours]); // events[i].getDescription(),
  }
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, details.length, 5).setValues(details);
  //var foo = "foo";
}
```

Edit: although you are still making calls to the Calendar service inside the loop. I should add this is untested but would be interested to hear if it makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks, setValues() in a loop was the bottleneck!

Comment: I did not understand why playing the script in de debugger with breakpoint after var foo = "foo"; took such a long time to finish, I thought it was the query, but it was setValues busy still rendering it's task! You really helped me out!

Comment: Actually still thinking why it became slower and slower: The combination of using setValues() in a loop with 10 Queries in tabs might also be the cause, because every time setValues() was called in the loop the 10 queries were probably also executed.